# Accidentally deleted Minecraft on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I accidentally deleted Minecraft on the Xbox 360 when I was deleting some worlds. I previously had deleted the profile that I had downloaded Minecraft on. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

> I deleted the profile I had downloaded Minecraft on

You can simply re-download the profile, then re-download Minecraft for free, since the purchase was made by that account.

Alternatively, you can download it again on your new profile (you will have to pay for it again), and any saves/worlds will be added back into Minecraft.